# How to color different sections of long bootstrap form

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using boostrap to create a form. There are three main sections, and I want each section to have its own color. The problem is that if I don't know how to do it without having to split them into different forms.

Currently, this is similar to what I have:

```
<div id="section-one" style="background-color:green">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <form role="form">
                    <h2>Section one</h2>
                    ...
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="section-two" style="background-color:black">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <form role="form">
                    <h2>Section two</h2>
                    ...
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="section-three" style="background-color:blue">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <form role="form">
                    <h2>Section three</h2>
                    ...
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried coloring each form, but it did not span the width of the browser. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: why not just wrap the form around the sections, and remove the `.container`, since that's what giving you the `width` issue?

Comment: @RobScott I removed the container and wrapped everything in the form tags. However, now I'm only getting one color throughout. This is what I have now: <div style="green"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"><form>...</form></div></div>

Comment: You need:   `<form><div id="section-one"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-8...."><h2>.....</h2><div class="form-group"><input .......... /></div></div></div></div></div><div id="section-two">.............`  I don't know what CSS you have on your `div` with the `id`, but this would be how you do it. Bootstrap's `container` class automatically comes with a `width` applied, which is why they don't "span the width of the browser". You also need to nullify the margin/padding on the `form` as well if boostrap auto-adds it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap's container class automatically comes with a width applied, which is why they don't "span the width of the browser". You also need to nullify the margin/padding on the form as well if boostrap auto-adds it

- Here's for [Boostrap's container](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) - check out the "Grid Options"
  section, row "container width".
- Here's boostrap's [form-group class](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php)

Since you're using Bootstrap, it also comes w/ a "Reset" CSS - [see here](http://cssreset.com/). You don't need to add the `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to the `body, html`.

Also another note - the `row` class will negative the margins. Therefore, whenever you use these, you need to use a `.col-XX-XX` class, either `lg`, `md`, `sm`, or `xs`. Reason being is b/c these have auto-padding on there, therefore nullifying the negative margin offset of the `row` class. Your second "section" didn't have one after the `class="row"` div

---

```
form  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form > div {
   margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

#section-one {
   background-color: red;
}
```

---

```
<form action="/something" method="post" name="blah-blah">
   <div id="section-one">
     <div class="container">  <-- bootstrap auto adds width to "container" class
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-8....">
               <h2>.....</h2>
               <div class="form-group">  <-- read about bootstrap's "form-group" class
                      <input .......... />
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section-two">
     <div class="container">
        .........
        .........
  <div class="form-group row">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it already looks a lot better. I added the following: form > container { margin: 0; width: 100%; padding:0 }. However there is still some whitespace between the rows and some on the sides.

Comment: Earlier I changed it to container-fluid, and removed the padding:0 feature. It worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your problem. But you can wrap all your html in one form. 
If you don't want margin, you can add

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Improved code:

```
<style>
   html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }
</style>
   <form>
   <div id="section-one" style="background-color:green">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2>Section one</h2>
                    ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="section-two" style="background-color:black">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                    <h2>Section two</h2>
                    ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="section-three" style="background-color:blue">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2>Section three</h2>
                    ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by using `container-fluid` instead of `container` as well as simplifying the HTML (you don't have to use individual containers) and if you're simply adding color to a background just apply it to the `row` itself with an ID/class since it won't alter anything structurally.

See Examples in Snippet.

```css
#section-one {
  background-color: red;
}
#section-two {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#section-three {
  background-color: pink;
}
/*EXAMPLE FORM*/

#section-one-2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#section-two-2 {
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#section-three-2 {
  background-color: pink;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="myForm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="section-one">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2>Section one</h2>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="section-two">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2>Section Two</h2>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="section-three">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2>Section Three</h2>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<hr>
<form class="myForm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="section-one-2">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Section 1" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="section-two-2">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Section 2" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="section-three-2">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Section 3" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```